# fromJSON + ldply: fix error incorrect number of subscripts on matrix

Tags: r, plyr, jsonlite

I have a JSON that has this structure:

```
{\"A\": [[\"x\", 0.2], [\"y\", 0.3], [\"z\", 0.3]], \"B\": [[\"x\", 0.2], [\"y\", 0.3]]}
```

I am trying to do this:

```
library(jsonlite)
library(plyr)
my_data <- fromJSON(my_json_file, flatten = TRUE)
my_data <- ldply(my_data, rbind)
```

but I get this error:

```
Error in output[rng, lcols[[i]]] <- matrices[[i]] : 
  incorrect number of subscripts on matrix
```

I tried to do `do.call(rbind, my_json_file)` and by doing that some information is missing because `ldply` should return

```
V1 | V2 | V3
A  | x  | 0.2
A  | y  | 0.3
A  | z  | 0.3
B  | x  | 0.2
B  | y  | 0.3
```

and `do.call` returns

```
V2 | V3
x  | 0.2
y  | 0.3
z  | 0.3
x  | 0.2
y  | 0.3
```

Is there a way to force `ldply` or to obtain the same result with `do.call`?

Comment: perhaps something like `do.call(rbind, lapply(fromJSON(my_json), data.frame))` to get you started

Comment: thanks !! that plus `my_data $id <- colnames(my_data)` works

Answer (score 1, accepted):

as @SymbolixAU started the solution when `ldply` doesn't work is

```
my_data <- do.call(rbind, lapply(fromJSON(my_json), data.frame))
my_data$id <- colnames(my_data)
```

Comment: glad it works - however, I would suspect that on large data sets the `do.call + rbind + lapply` may not be efficient.

Comment: yes, I had to use `mclapply` but at least it works... no idea of why `ldply` didn't